# Angular2: ts - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Below is the code that has the logic that changes the rows, cols, according to my business needs. When I keep this code, in my Angular2 ts code, I am getting  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target error at .forEach(...

```
var data = [{ Id: "a", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "b", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "1" }, { Id: "4", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "3" }, { Id: "c", ColumnLocation: "1", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "d", ColumnLocation: "1", RowLocation: "2" }, { Id: "e", ColumnLocation: "2", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "e", ColumnLocation: "2", RowLocation: "2" }];

data.forEach(function (col, row) {
                return function (o) {
                    if (col !== o.ColumnLocation) {
                        col = o.ColumnLocation;
                        row = 0;
                    }
                    if (+o.RowLocation !== row) {
                        o.RowLocation = row.toString();
                    }
                    row++;
                }
            }());
```

Comment: Where is `data`? Did you mean to do `array.forEach`?

Comment: What's `data`? You use `array` EDIT: Bah. Frank beat me to it :)

Comment: Its not array, it is data. apologies..

Comment: Ok, so now the function you pass to `forEach` would actually be getting different things passed in (the element in the array, the index, and the array). Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example. Can you update your question to take that into account?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the question.

Comment: Do you still get errors?

Comment: Yes. I am using data only (not array) in my code. I am still getting the errors.

Comment: Can you show where `col` and `row` are defined? I just noticed that the function you pass to `forEach` is immediately invoked, which means the inner function is actually the function used by `forEach` on each element. That inner function references `col` and `row` which I assume is defined somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in order to use self executing function with parameters you need to provide those parameters.

```js
let myCol; // or you can set this to an initial value
let myRow;

data.forEach(function (col, row) {
            return function (o) {
                // your logic here
            };
        }(myCol, myRow));
```

Your typescript compiler is complaining because your function takes two parameters `col` and `row` but you are invoking it without any parameter.

Comment: what are x and y here ?

Comment: I was going to write this as well, except the code does compile. But you are right about needing to pass `myCol` and `myRow` at the bottom for it to behave correctly.

Comment: @FrankModica but what does x and y represent here

Comment: @indra257 x and y are placeholders for whatever you want your col and row to be. They can be numbers or references to some other parameters. You can just write let myCol, myRow if you want to start without any value.